# Mobile Safari select onclick event

Tags: javascript, onclick, mobile-safari

My page has select tag with `onclick=""` event:

```
<select onclick="OnChange()">
```

It works only on the second click with mobile Safari - other browsers work fine.

How to get the first `onclick` event with mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `onChange` attribute instead. It's more suited to what you want. Also, using `onClick` doesn't factor in tabbed access to the field...